# What's the proper way to wrap [NSString stringWithFormat:]?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Assume I have a method with the signature:

```
+ (NSString *) myFormattedString:(NSString *)format, ...;
```

And I want it to prepend a string of my choice (e.g. @"Foo: "). I guess the best way is to use [myString initWithFormat:arguments:], but how would you implement this method?

---

<strike>I tried doing the following, but I get the warning as specified in the comment:</strike>

```
+ (NSString *) myFormattedString:(NSString *)format, ... {
  char *buffer;
  [format getCString:buffer maxLength:[format length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

  va_list args;
  va_start(args, buffer); // WARNING: second parameter of 'va_start' not last named argument

  NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];
  [str autorelease];

  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Foo: %@.", str];
}
```

The reason I'm assuming va_start() can take in a (char *) is because of the example I saw on the [manual page of STDARG(3)](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/stdarg.3.html). Feel free to completely rewrite the method if I'm doing it totally wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think what you want is something like:

```
+ (NSString *) myFormattedString:(NSString *)format, ... {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);
  NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args] autorelease];
  va_end(args);
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Foo: %@.", str];
}
```

The `stdarg.h` `va_`* macros are used when a function (or, in this case, method) takes a variable number of arguments, as specified by "`...`".  `va_start()` is used to find the start of where the variable number of arguments begins.  As such, it needs to know a functions/methods last argument (the one just before the "`...`") in order to determine where the variable number of arguments starts.  This is a somewhat simplified explanation since what actually happens under the hood is very ABI/Compiler specific.  The most important point is that the second argument to `va_start()` is always the name of the variable 'just before the "`...`"'.

`va_end()` should be "called" (it's really a macro, not a function) for maximum portability.  Again, this whole variable arguments thing is deep, deep black magic.  Depending on the specifics of the compiler and ABI, `va_end()` may not do anything at all.  On the other hand, failure to use `va_end()` may cause your program to crash when the `return` statement is reached because the stack frame (if there even is one) is no longer properly set up to actually perform a return.

Comment: Woops, I misunderstood how va_start() works. I guess http://numbergrinder.com/node/35 doesn't explain it clearly enough. I thought the second parameter to va_start() was the actual count of how many params were sent to the function; and that it had an 'overload' which took in a format string that determined the count based on how many unescaped %'s there were in the format string... Wow that makes it so much easier that you don't have to determine the count yourself. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 8):

You've almost got it; just a couple of tweaks:

```
+ (NSString *) myFormattedString:(NSString *)format, ... {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);

  NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];
  [str autorelease];

  va_end(args);

  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Foo: %@.", str];
}
```

That should do what you're looking for.